# extract the second found matching substring using Postgresql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, substring

I use the bellow query to extract a value from a column that stores JSON objects.

The issue with it, it does only pull the first value matching to the `regex` inside `SUBSTRING` which is `-$4,000.00`, is there's a parameter to pass to the `SUBSTRING` to pull the value `-$1,990.00` as well in another column.

```
SELECT attribute_actions_text
, SUBSTRING(attribute_actions_text FROM '"Member [Dd]iscount:":"(.+?)"') AS column_1
, '' AS column_2

FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('[{"Member Discount:":"-$4,000.00"},{"Member discount:":"-$1,990.00"}]')
   , (NULL)
   ) ls(attribute_actions_text)
```

Desired result :

```
column_1        column_2  
-$4,000.00      -$1,990.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH data(id,attribute_actions_text) as (
  VALUES
      (1,'[{"Member Discount:":"-$4,000.00"},{"Member Discount:":"-$1,990.00"}]')
    , (2,'[{"Member Discount:":"-$4,200.00"},{"Member Discount:":"-$1,890.00"}]')
    , (3,NULL)
), match as (
  SELECT
    id,
    m,
    ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS r
  FROM data, regexp_matches(data.attribute_actions_text, '"Member [Dd]iscount:":"(.+?)"', 'g') AS m
)
SELECT
   id
  ,(select m from match where id = d.id AND r=1) as col1
  ,(select m from match where id = d.id AND r=2) as col2
  FROM data d
```

Result

`1,"{-$4,000.00}","{-$1,990.00}"
2,"{-$4,200.00}","{-$1,890.00}"
3,NULL,NULL`